# Wanting to connect an Android device app (Java programming) to NetBeans 8.0

Tags: java, android, mysql, netbeans

Wanting to connect an Android app (Java programming) to Netbeans 8.0. Have already connected MySQL database to netbeans, wanting the app to be able to access the database. Has anybody got any suggestions how to go about doing this ? or any useful tutorials please ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://nbandroid.org/ - you can find a set of modules to enable Android development there.